# ServicesStack ORMLITE C#

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, orm

Estoy trabajando en un poryecto universitario, en C#, anteriormente trabajaba con una version actualizada de ServicesStack, pero al serun poryecto mas grande, necesito de la version Free (3.9.71) pero en esta version al realizar operaciones como

Insert
Delete 
Update

No retorna ningun valor, por lo que todo el codigo que tenia viejo no me funciona, este es el codigo como lo tengo ahorita

var db = BDConn.Connector();

```
            var result  = db.Update(aula); // Aqui da error porque el metodo de esta version es VOID

            if (result > 0) // Por ente esto tambien da error
            {
                return new Resultado
                {
                    Codigo = 1,
                    Mensaje = "Aula modificada correctamente"
                };

            }
            else
            {
                return new Resultado
                {
                    Codigo = 99,
                    Mensaje = "Problemas al modificar aula"
                };

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Entonces como puedo hacer para cambiar un poco el meotodoy estar seguro que se agregó, modifico o elimino correctamente si no retorna nada.

Comment: ¿Y si solo tratas de hacer `Update`? Ya que la función es `void` _debería_ arrojar alguna excepción cuando el método falla, ¿Has probado a ver si algo así sucede en una base de datos de prueba?

Comment: Si, pero la idea es que quiero retornar algo cuando se realice algun CRUD

Comment: Y qué te impide retornar el error cuando el metodo falla?